# count inside group_concat not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query that will count the number of count per row, and the number of people having some value (and Ideally the percentage beside) inside the rows using group_concat, the problem is that for some reason is not working as expected.

can I use group_contact(count(*))?

Comment: [If it is possible to create a live example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .. of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: added code as suggested

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not that easy. `GROUP_CONCAT()` doesn't work that way.

My advice, forget about `GROUP_CONCAT()`. A database is there to store and get you the data, not to format it nicely. That's done in presentation layer or application layer.

So instead of

```
SELECT room, course, teacher, count(*), group_concat(country) 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY room, course, teacher;
```

do this:

```
SELECT room, course, teacher, country, count(*)
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY room, course, teacher, country;
```

You will get something like this instead:

```
Room A  Course A    Teacher A  ES  2
Room A  Course A    Teacher A  MX  1
Room A  Course A    Teacher A  IT  1
Room A  Course A    Teacher A  JP  1
Room B ...
...
```

Then sum the counts on application level. Or you could do

```
SELECT room, course, teacher, country, count(*)
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY room, course, teacher, country
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Then you will get this:

```
Room A  Course A    Teacher A  ES    2
Room A  Course A    Teacher A  MX    1
Room A  Course A    Teacher A  IT    1
Room A  Course A    Teacher A  JP    1
NULL    NULL        NULL       NULL  5
Room B ...
...
```

Comment: Well, do it on the on the representation is easy, but unfortunately that's not an option for me in this case. It must be possible to do this with a query, if not I will have to create a store procedure, but I preferred to do it with a single query.

Comment: Well, I can have a try. Please provide sample data.

Comment: there is on the question and also there is a sqlfiddle. thanks

Comment: MySQL allows this (but this will actually change in future versions), but the rule is, that every column in the select clause should be either in the group by clause as well or an aggregate function should be applied on it. Otherwise a random(!) row is picked off the group to display.

Comment: I had simplified the schema just for the demo, but the whole schema is correct